# Match an array to an array of objects and get values

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS.
I Have an array of object like described below and I have an array with values. Is it possible for me to have an expected output described?

```
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

var myArray = [4,6,8]

Output: [3,5,7]
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question immediately. Is the question how to subtract 1 from the `myArray` elements? Is it to loop through the list of objects in `jsObjects` and return `a`'s value given `b`'s value? What other research was done?

Comment: Is it to loop through the list of objects in jsObjects and return a's value given b's value? 
I had tried using filter method but did not know how to use it with map.

Comment: That is what should be included in the question. Steps done previously or other research. Looks like you have your answer now. Please keep this in mind for future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

[**`Array.prototype.includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

And [**`Array.prototype.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

var myArray = [4,6,8]

var resArray = jsObjects.filter(i => myArray.includes(i.b)).map(i => i.a);
console.log(resArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `new Map()` to store key-value pairs, where `b` is your key and `a` is your value. After that, you can `.map()` your array of `b` values to an array of `a` values using the map you constructed:

```js
const jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

const myArray = [4,6,8];

const search = new Map(jsObjects.map(({a, b}) => [b, a]));
const res = myArray.map(v => search.get(v));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using higher order function like `filter, map, find e.t.c`, but as you say you are new to javascript - i think this is the simplest way of understanding and getting the expected result.

```js
var jsObjects = [
   {a: 1, b: 2}, 
   {a: 3, b: 4}, 
   {a: 5, b: 6}, 
   {a: 7, b: 8}
];

var myArray = [4,6,8]

var finalArray = [];

for(let bValue of myArray) {
  for(let item in jsObjects) {
    if(bValue == jsObjects[item].b) {
      finalArray.push(jsObjects[item].a);
    }
  }
}

console.log(finalArray); // [3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are N ways of doing that, none of them without adding a bit of logic.

Even though you are new to JS, I advise you to use HOF like `reduce` ([take a look here to know more about HOF](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99)).

Here's an example how to do it:

```
const jsObjects = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 3, b: 4 },
  { a: 5, b: 6 },
  { a: 7, b: 8 }
];

const myArray = [4, 6, 8];
const result = jsObjects.reduce((result, entry) => {
  if (myArray.includes(entry.b)) {
    result.push(entry.a);

    return result;
  }

  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result) // [3, 5, 7];
```